# Refresh page without hashtag in Angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest, http

I have Spring+Angular+Rest webapp . I remove hashtage from url on this way ..

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

in index.html

```
 <base href="/webapptest/">
```

Now, home page look OK, and everything work great .
 Looks like  : `http://localhost:8080/webapptest/`

Problem is when , after i remove hashtag, when I go to second page ... `http://localhost:8080/webapptest/page2`

First time page is show , but after reload  ... error 404 . I read that is problem on server side, becose i chabge url... but I don't know what to change ... 
This is Spring Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="api/files")
public class FileController {

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody() String getFile(HttpServletRequest request) throws      IOException  {
    String htmlString = "";
    try {....
 ...
return htmlString;
}
```

This is controller and method which use page2 , the same controller use also home page but another method . Have someone idea what is problem and how to solve reload page without hashtag ?

app.js :

```
uploadFile.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'resources/html/home.html',
        controller : 'uploadFileController'
    })
    .when('/page2', {
        templateUrl : 'resources/html/page2.html',
        controller : 'uploadFileControllerAdmin'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
if(window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
}])
```

Comment: Google: "spring angular html5 mode"

Comment: share code for yr angular app.config

Comment: I try many way, also with @RequestMapping but then got error or is notting happen . Do you know in my case where to put RequestMapping and how in controller .. ?

Answer (score 1):

When you initially request `/webapptest`, your browser makes the request to your server (e.g. Spring App), which it returns the `index.html`.

Once you've loaded index.html and your Angular app/module, it will handle all request that matches it routing relative to it's path -- here's the relevant [Angular reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), specifically concerning **html5mode**

> Note that in this mode, Angular intercepts all links (subject to the
>   "Html link rewriting" rules below) and updates the url in a way that
>   never performs a full page reload

So from your Angular app, any request to `/webapptest/page2` will match it's routing

```
.when('/page2', {
    templateUrl : 'resources/html/page2.html',
```

and be handle exclusively by Angular, which triggers Angular to request the corresponding templateUrl -- `resources/html/page2.html`.

At this point the url will be `/webapptest/page2`, but your browser never actually requested that from your server. But when you hit refresh, your browser takes over, sees the `/webapptest/page2` in it's history/location and request that from your server, which I'm assuming your server doesn't have so you get a 404.

---

To fix this, you need to configure your server to let Angular handle all request to `/webapptest/**`, which basically means you need to map all `/webapptest/**` to index.html.

You can have a simple view controller

```
@Controller
public class SpaController {

  @RequestMapping(value={"/webapptest/**"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String app() {
    return "index"; 
  }
}
```

or add the above mapping to Spring [ViewControllerRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ViewControllerRegistry.html) if you're already using it.

---

BTW - is this check needed?

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

Doesn't $location fallback to Hashbang mode for legacy browser that don't support html5mode?